# nested form update issue

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

i am using rails 4 and i have problem in nested form. i have used nested form in my application and through it values are getting stored properly into the database. i have used strong parameters properly. but the problem is that when i am updating the same form the nested fields values are not getting displayed in the respected text boxes.how to fix this issue?
this is what i have used in my controller

```
def vendor_info_params
  params.require(:vendor_info).permit(:name, :primary_contact_name, :phone, :address, :city,
  :vendor_references_attributes=>[:id, :vendor_info_id, :name, :email])
end
```

and this is what i have used in my _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :vendor_references, @vendor_info.vendor_references.build do |builder| %>
     <%= render "vendor_references", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Welcome at stackoverflow, Patil. I like to read questions where a new sentence starts with an uppercase letter. Your question looks a bit messy to me like it is. To your question, in former versions you needed to specify  `allow_nested_attributes_for :vendor_reference` ... in your model, i think.

Answer (score 1):

You specify a collection in your `fields_for` : `@vendor_info.vendor_references.build`

The `build` method is an alias of `new` so your collection contains only one new vendor reference. If you want to see all your references just do :

```
<%= f.fields_for :vendor_references, @vendor_info.vendor_references do |builder| %>
     <%= render "vendor_references", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

If you need a new reference for each update or new call, you can add it in your controller method like :

```
def new
  @vendor_info = VendorInfo.new
  @vendor_info.vendor_references.build
end
```